# Akavache crashing android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, akavache

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and have this method to fetch my user object

```
    public static async Task<Object> GetCurrentUser()
    {
        try
        {
            return await BlobCache.UserAccount.GetObject<Object>("NewUser").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The code works well on my iOS emulator but keeps crashing on the android with this error

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException The given key 'NewUser'
>   was not present in the cache.

Please I need help

Comment: So your cache does not have the key you are searching for. Do a sanity test and make sure you add that key before you retrieve it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be caught in the `Catch` though?

Comment: Try, deleting everything in your bins rebuild and try again. XF is finicky about leftover artifacts lingering.

Comment: @JonStødle my thoughts exactly. For a first time user there will be nothing in the cache until they login.